# Like affects the result of count()

Tags: mysql, count, sql-like

I am trying to select the number of distinct rows with a certain string using `like` but instead of counting only the distinct rows a certain column(`dest_msisdn`) has ,the query fetches based on what like matches.

I have a table `incoming_sms` which has the messages and the originating number column(`dest_msisdn`). Since there are thousands of messages,i only want to count the messages that arrived `2` days ago and the messages must be `like` `%Acc%`.
This is my query

`SELECT COUNT(distinct dest_msisdn)  FROM incoming_sms  where text_message like '%Acc%' AND in_date >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY ) ;`

I was expecting the query to give me `1` row but instead it gives me `2`.

Why is like acting this way?.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense.  Can you edit it and provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: As your question stands, there's no reason for your query to return 10, 2, 1, or any other number. We need to see the data to judge.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting the `count`, go ahead and select `dest_msisdn`.  Are they different?  If so, there's your reason.